# Got socket error trying to find package at https://pub.dartlang.org

Tags: flutter

Hello i have been creating my first flutter project and i got this problem, is there a possible reason or solution.
Got socket error trying to find package cupertino_icons at https://pub.dartlang.org

Comment: Please add the exact and full error output to your question. Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: i fixed the issue, i downloaded and enabled a vpn and the errr was fixed, thank you for reaching out.

Answer (score 0):

A socket error is basically a connection error. And in the case of running `flutter pub get` a socket error is very likely due to a firewall. Check your firewall settings. Ensure that no component of Flutter, Dart, or your IDE is being blocked by your firewall or antivirus program.

Another possible issue is like the example [this GitHub post](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/62316). The error was caused by multiple instances of Flutter installed in the machine.

Comment: Yea , thats correct , its normally caused by a firewal

Comment: Can you give some love and accept my answer?